# What is an example of a situation in which FTP and FTPS would be in the place of HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: https, ftps

I used to think that FTPS was better for downloading large files, but through more research I have found that HTTPS is actually faster and more secure. So then in what situations does FTP or FTPS actually provide an advantage over HTTP or HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

The FTP and HTTP protocols are 2 different things.
The main advantage/goal of FTP is the command set (LIST, PWD, MKDIR, SYSTEM).
It's perfect for remote file management system (like FileZilla).

More details: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959